# How can I show basic class attributes from intellisense later (like after dot) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I show **basic** class attributes in **VSCode Intellisense** after code is written (the dot is already written)?

When I write and press a {dot} then only this "direct attributes and methods" are shown:

[image: Intellisense after dot]

But later, whenever I place the cursor after dot and press {ctrl}+{space}, this extended list is displayed (you see here only first part of "a" letter):

[image: Intellisense later]

Most often I want to use / I searching for the direct method / attribute, so, this extended list is less clear.

**Can I temporary switch from this long list to simplified to show only basic methods?**
Or I need to delete dot and type it again to show it?

Sorry, this is probably a simple question, but searching in documentation and shortcuts list didn't help me. And I do not want to search in the long list if it's a simpler option.

Comment: Just put another dot before the dot temporarily like this `ApplicationData.[CursorHere].prototype`